# Adding a custom email order recipient for specific product attributes in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

This is my first question here, and I need your help. I tried researching this topic, but did not manage to understand what exactly I am doing wrong, so please bear with me.
I am using the following code:
`
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'add_recipient', 10, 2 );
function add_recipient( $recipient, $order )
{
if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;

```
// Additional email recipient
$additional_email1 = "email#1@email.com";
$additional_email2 = "email#2@email.com";

// The term slug
$term_slug1 = "d1";
$term_slug2 = "d2";

$has_term = false;

// Iterating through each order item
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_obj) {
    $product_id = $item_obj->get_product_id();
    $product_obj = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $product_attributes = $product_obj->get_attributes();
    foreach( $product_attributes as $taxonomy_key => $term_value ){

        if( $taxonomy_key == "pa_d" && $term_value == $term_slug1 ){
            $recipient .= ','. $additional_email1;
            $has_term = true;
            break; // stop searching
        }

        if( $taxonomy_key == "pa_d" && $term_value == $term_slug2 ){
            $recipient .= ','. $additional_email2;
            $has_term = true;
            break; // stop searching
        }
    }
    if( $has_term ) break; // stop the main loop
}
return $recipient;
```

} `

I am now trying to adapt this code to work with the parent product. Ideally, this code should work for both variable and non-varible products, such that if a product contains the term "d1", regardless of whether it is variable or not, the email should always go to email#1. Same for d2 and email#2.

However, the code is not outputting any errors. Should I use $product->get_id() instead? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. I revised your code. try the below code.

```
// Additional email recipient
$additional_email1 = "email#1@email.com";
$additional_email2 = "email#2@email.com";

// The term slug
$term_slug1 = "d1";
$term_slug2 = "d2";

$has_term = false; // Initializing

// Loop though order items
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ){
    // Only for product variations
    if( $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ){
        $product = $item->get_product(); // The WC_Product Object
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Product ID

        // Loop through product attributes set in the variation
        foreach( $product->get_attributes() as $taxonomy => $term_slug ){
            // comparing attribute parameter value with current attribute value
            if ( $term_slug === $term_slug1 ) {
                $has_term = true;
                $recipient .= ','. $additional_email1;
            }

            if ( $term_slug === $term_slug2 ) {
                $has_term = true;
                $recipient .= ','. $additional_email2;
            }
        }
    }

    if( $has_term ) break; // stop the main loop

}

return $recipient;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply! I tried to use this code, but I am also trying it for simple products. I need it to work for both simple products and variable ones, so what should I do precisely? Thank you!